# ListView e AniIndicator

Tags: delphi, listview, thread

Se alguém puder dar um help, Estou com o seguinte problema : Tenho dois componentes em uma form, um ListView e um AniIndicator, estou carregando os dados do ListView em blocos vindos do banco de dados conforme a demanda. gostaria que o AniIndicator fica-se rodando enquanto carrega os registros, mas o AniIndicator para de rodar quando carrego novos registros no ListView, já tentei fazer com Thread mas não consegui. Se alguém tiver uma luz.

Comment: já possui algo programado? Mostra para nós como esta carregando os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o código abaixo de teste e deu tudo certo, tente utilizar a `procedure` `Application.ProcessMessages` durante o `loop` do carregamento dos dados no `TListView`

Segue:

```
procedure TesteAniIndicator;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  AniIndicator1.Visible := True;
  AniIndicator1.Enabled := True;
  try
    for I := 0 to 1000 do
    begin
      Sleep(10);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  finally
    AniIndicator1.Enabled := False;
    AniIndicator1.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```